# back to back ngui tween play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tween, ngui

I have an object "**Crane**" which **moving/animate** with help of **tween**. Different parts of crane moving using tween  and playing back to back with help of **onFinish** event of tween. Everything working is fine but some time my crane tween stuck in different points/onFinish event. I don't know what is the problem I have check my code everything is fine maybe the problem is in back to back tween play on Onfinish events.! 
So have anyone experience this problem ?I want it solution that how to ensure back to back tween play.

Remember: if one tween didn't play then the second one will not be played cause the second tween is dependent upone the completion of first tween onFinish